# How can I print data (object of arraylist) one by one on clicking a next/previous button without actually reloading the JSP page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web-deployment

```
<%  ArrayList<QuesnBean> list =new ArrayList<QuesnBean>();

list = (ArrayList<QuesnBean>)request.getAttribute("question"); 
int i=0, l=list.size();
    for(QuesnBean qbean : list)
    {
     qbean = list.get(i);

         out.print("<br><br> Q.No: "+ (i+1) +"  ");
         out.println(qbean.getQuesn()+"<br>");
         out.println("<br> <input type='radio' name='o1'> "+qbean.getOp1());
         out.println("<br> <input type='radio' name='o1'> "+qbean.getOp2());
         out.println("<br> <input type='radio' name='o1'> "+qbean.getOp3());
     out.println("<br> <input type='radio' name='o1'> "+qbean.getOp4());

         if(i<=l){
            i++;
            }
    } 
 %>
```

I expect one object of qbean at a time on clicking next/previous button but i m getting all objects stored in qbean at a same time same page . I need the actual solution of implementation.

Comment: Can i have the code please , any one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look for asynchronous techinques, like AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML)

Here is a quick introduction of how it works: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: but still how to implement in three separate buttons i.e. NEXT ,PREVIOUS & SUBMIT, i m not able to resolve it still !